# Unable to upload image to firebase storage from python server

Tags: python, android, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am creating an android app which sends an image to python server and from my python server I want to upload that received image to firebase storage. My problem is that when I try to upload the received image from python server only the filename is stored in the specified collection but my image doesn't upload. My firebase storage looks like this
[Firebase storage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pblw.png)

In the attached screenshot the first image starting with Actual is the one that I upload from android and the second starting with processed is the one that I am trying to upload from python but unable to do that. The file type is also different that the one uploaded from android. Below is my code that I am using to upload the image from my server:
Function where I receive image from android:

```
def handle_request():
    print(flask.request.files)
    print(flask.request.form)
    imagefile = flask.request.files['image']
    userID = flask.request.form['user_ID']
    upload_to_firebase(imagefile, filename, userID)
```

Function which stores the image to firebase storage.

```
def upload_to_firebase(file, filename, userID):
    firebase = Firebase(config)
    firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
    storage = firebase.storage()
    storage.child(userID + "/" + filename + "/Processed_" + filename+"").put(file)
    downloadURL = storage.child(userID + "/" + filename + "/Processed_" + filename+"").get_url(None)
```

Is there any way I can pass the content type image/jpeg while sending the image or any other way I can fix this. I have searched a lot this solution but none have worked so far.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that as explained on the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#python):

> You can use the bucket references returned by the Admin SDK in conjunction with the official Google Cloud Storage client libraries to upload, download, and modify content in the buckets associated with your Firebase projects

Therefore you'll need to modify your `upload_to_firebase` function to something similar as explained here on the relevant section of the [Google Cloud Storage client library for Python](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#aria-tab-python):

```
from google.cloud import storage


def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(
        "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
            source_file_name, destination_blob_name
        )
    )
```

where you could obtain the `bucket_name` variable from the [name property](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html#module-google.cloud.storage.bucket)of the bucket object you define with the Firebase Admin SDK (e.g. if you are [using the default bucket](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#use_a_default_bucket) of your project):

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import storage

cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'storageBucket': '<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com'
})

bucket = storage.bucket()
```

and the `source_file_name` will correspond to the full path of the uploaded image within the server serving your Flask application.

Notice that you could end up with disk space issues if not properly deleting or managing the files uploaded to the Python server, so be careful on that regards.

Comment: Thanks for the help Daniel. I implemented this code and my image is being stored in firebase storage at the desired path but only the image that I save first on my device. How can I skip the file path part and directly pass the image that I am getting from my client so that I don't have to save and load the image.

Comment: Addition to the first comment. When I try to open the stored image in firebase console a loader appears over it but it doesn't display the image. Rest of the property like content type etc is being stored fine.

Comment: Also how can I get the image url instead of downloading the image from firebase storage?

Comment: I found this [code](https://gist.github.com/juliooa/60fa6385c85aa30137dc2c75fe98ffed#file-upload_image-py) (haven't tested it) that you could adapt to your use case (it uses the `upload_from_string()` instead of the `upload_from_filename()` method. To get the URL take advantage of the [public_url](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.public_url) property of the Blobs.